# find all the value of x,y z?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be the complex $3 × 3$ matrix

$A = \begin{bmatrix}2&0&0 \\ x&2 & 0 \\y&z&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Find all triples $(x, y, z)$ for which the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A $ are different.

My attempts : the Characteristic polynomial of $A  = (\lambda +1)(\lambda -2)^2$

Case $1$:  if  $x=y= z \neq 0$ ,then minimial polynomial of   $A  = (\lambda +1)(\lambda -2)^2$

Case $2$ : if $x=y= z =0$,then minimial polynomial of   $A  = (\lambda +1)(\lambda -2)$

Here  im confused that how  can i find  all triples $(x, y, z)$ for which the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A $ are different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The minimal polynomial is either $(\lambda+1)(\lambda-2)$ or $(\lambda+1)(\lambda-2)^2.$

We can try to compute $(A+I)(A-2I)$ and see whether we obtain $0$.

$$A+I=\begin{bmatrix}3&0&0 \\ x&3 & 0 \\y&z&0\end{bmatrix}, A-2I=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0 \\ x&0 & 0 \\y&z&-3\end{bmatrix} $$

$$(A+I)(A-2I)=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 3x & 0 & 0\\ xz & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix} $$

Can read off the required condition from the matrix above?

Edit:

We obtain $3x=0$ and $xz=0$.

which means $x=0$ and ($x=0$ or $z=0$)

which is equivalent to $x=0$.

Comment: that mean  triples are  $(x,y,z) =(x,xz,z)$...is it correct???

Comment: Remember we want $(A+I)(A-2I)=0$ right?

Comment: ya,,,.....But  how  can i find that  Triple (x,yz) ?? as  u show that  $3x$  in 2nd row   and $xz$ in 3rd row ?  i mean  that how we can find that..

Comment: every element of $(A+I)(A-2I)=0$, so go through every element of the matrix, equate it to zero?

Comment: that mean $ 3x= 0, xz = 0$  but  here  we r getting  $x= 0,z=0$ that mean Triple $(x,y,z) = (0,0,z)$   is the requires answer ?? is its correct

Comment: It means $3x=0$ and $xz=0$. there is no constraint on $y$.

Comment: thanks  i got its   that mean Triple $(x,y,z) = (0,y,0)$ ? is its correct ??

Comment: edited, note that you can simplify and realized that there is indeed no constraint on $z$ as well.

Comment: thanks  a lots @siong Thye Goh

Comment: That mean  Triple $(x,y,z) = (0,y,z)$  is  the requires answer ? is its correct??

Comment: yes, that is correct.