# Characteristic and Minimal Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

[Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2762855/find-all-the-value-of-x-y-z?rq=1)

Let $A$ be the complex $3 \times 3$ matrix

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 \\ a & 2 & 0 \\ b & c & -1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ for which the characteristic and minimal polynomials of $A$ are different.

Comment: The characteristic polynomial here is (x-2)^2*(x+1). So the choices for minimal polynomial are (x-2)^2*(x+1), (x-2)*(x+1) or (x-2)*(x+1)^2.

Comment: Mathjax and $\LaTexX!  Try them, you'll like them, and so will your readers!  I edited your post.  Also, ***+1!!!***  Welcome to MSE! Cheers!

Comment: @YadatiKiran The minimal polynomial won't be $(x-2)(x+1)^2$.